# Entity form reusable form part

Tags: entities

I am creating more than 50 entity forms and major parts (contains 20 fields) of these forms are exactly same. Forms are different from each others only one or two field. If I need to edit major and exactly same part of these forms I must repeat editing process for all forms. Are there any aproach to solve this problem? I need edit major part of forms only one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Entity forms**, also know as **Reusable forms**, because they are not created directly in the process but in the entity that contains their information, that is, in the **Context** entity.

Now you please take a look at "Reuse of field collection entity type on more than one collection field?", a drupal community question explains something about it(google for it). 
I hope this would help though.

Thank you.